# Should an errata contain header and footer text and a page number?

Tags: research-process, paper-submission, errors-erratum

When writing a paper and adding an errata list (spelling out some mistakes that were made in previous versions of the paper), should that list contain the same meta-information as other pages, i.e. header and footer text and a page number? (If it's relevant, I am using APA for this paper but cannot find any information on the subject.) Additionally, should it be included in a table of contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Consult the [APA Style manual](http://www.apastyle.org/), which you can probably check out of a library. The full manual is not available online, although I was able to find [this information about lists](http://www.apastyle.org/learn/quick-guide-on-formatting.aspx#Lists). You may want to consider the guidelines for appendices, since this list sounds like an appendix (if it is long). [This document from Walden University(pdf)](http://writingcenter.waldenu.edu/Documents/How_to_Format_and_Cite_an_Appendix_in_APA_Style.pdf) describes how to format appendices using APA), but is mum on header and footer. I expect that you should include such information.
2. Consult the recipient of your paper. If this paper is being written for a class, ask your instructor. If this paper is to be submitted to a journal or conference, then said journal or conference likely has detailed guidelines available for lists and appendices. If such information is not available, you should contact a member of the editorial staff.